# ahk POST request using JSON issue

Tags: json, autohotkey

I'm developing **REST API**, and It should respond on request made by ahk script. I use **node.js** as server and **mongodb** as database. I tested **POST** my API  in **postman** and it is working. But when I send **POST** requests from my ahk script, something goes wrong.

---

Here is my code

```
URL := "http://localhost:8000/createPlayer"
HttpObj := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")




HttpObj.Open("POST", URL, 0)
HttpObj.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")


json_str := ({"name": "Any Name"})


Body = json_str
HttpObj.Send(Body)

MsgBox, %Body%
Result := HttpObj.ResponseText
Status := HttpObj.Status
msgbox % "status: " status "`n`nresult: " result
```

---

I tried different variations of json_str, but that didn't helped. I would really appreciate if you help me

Answer (score 2):

I can see you've made the classic newbie mistake (we all make this mistake at one point at least):
Change:

```
Body = json_str
```

to

```
Body := json_str
```

which will set the Body to the contents of the variable json_str, rather what it's currently doing which is setting Body directly to the string "json_str".